# Merge result of multiple components from multiple services in angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I have scenario where I have two child components in app component. Both child components are using two different services for their results. I want to execute those services in onInit of respective component and load two components independently. Is it possible using forkjoin? Can anybody give me simple example?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. If you want to know when the two calls are finish you can emit an observable to parent an take the account. So, your parent can be like

```
<app-component1 (finish)="sendData($event,0)"></app-component1>
<app-component2 (finish)="sendData($event,1)"></app-component2>

data:any[];
sendData(data:any,value:number)
{
   this.data[value]=data;
   if (this.data[0] && this.data[1])
     console.log("The two component received data")
}
```

See https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event